# Processing / .NET interop?

Tags: c#, java, .net, processing

I'd like to call into a .NET assembly for some data and library functions from a [Processing](http://processing.org) user interface. What's the best way to achieve this? Expose a web service? A [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#RESTful_web_services) API? Some godforsaken processing/Silverlight monstrosity?

Good ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

One approach might be to expose the desired data and functionality to COM via the REGASM utility and then use a Java-COM bridge to get to it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Processing (is [this](http://processing.org/) what you are talking about?), but if it's standard JVM-based environment, then [JNBridge](http://www.jnbridge.com/) is a very solid solution, assuming the pricing works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I am author of [jni4net](http://jni4net.sf.net/), open source interprocess bridge between JVM and CLR. It's build on top of JNI and PInvoke. No C/C++ code needed. I hope it will help you.